# Separate pattern by Z coordinates

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I ended up with a kinda cool looking pattern for donut icing.
I've been trying to use it as a mask between two materials (icing and pastry)
The problem I'm facing is that I can't figure out how to get the bottom of the sphere to be black so I can properly use this pattern as a mask. I tried with object and textures coordinates but no luck so far.
Is it even possible or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

[image]

Comment: Can use two materials on this same object?

Comment: Yes, you can use the mix shader node with a mask as Fac

Comment: Was talking about adding another material. If you don't want that, the simple way is to use a UV map.

Comment: Yes that would do the trick. This is something I'm doing for nodevember so no UV maps allowed if I read the rules correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arctan2 into division step is turning this into a radial gradient.  Instead of a light and a dark half you have light and dark quarters of the mesh, basically, and the way you've ramped the color is kind of hiding the problem from you.

[image]

So I think what you are asking for is not going to happen without some changes to the math leading up to it.  If you take the output of your noise texture into a math node set to Less Than you may find something you like, or try the following:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I have a bit of trouble understanding what the mix vector/noise does. The output is a "noised" vesion of the textures coordinates ?

Comment: Precisely.  The XYZ data can be forced down the same paths as RGB and as such can be used with a MixRGB node to give us a handy little factor slider, or you could even plug in another texture as your factor.  It's fun to mess around with your coordinate space before feeding it into a texture.  The output varies between 0 and 1 quite a lot, and it looked like what you wanted was a solid mask, and that's what the last divide gives us, note that we check the clamp box to limit it to the 0-1 range.

Comment: Thank you again for the explanation, that is an excellent trick ^^